# Fill in values of dataframes per groups of rows

Tags: python, pandas

Let's suppose that I have the following dataset:

```
Time    Geography           Sex     Population
1990    Northern Ireland    Male    NA
1990    Northern Ireland    Female  NA
1990    Northern Ireland    Total   NA
1991    Northern Ireland    Male    NA
1991    Northern Ireland    Female  NA
1991    Northern Ireland    Total   NA
1992    Northern Ireland    Male    792100
1992    Northern Ireland    Female  831100
1992    Northern Ireland    Total   1623300
1993    Northern Ireland    Male    812100
1993    Northern Ireland    Female  851100
1993    Northern Ireland    Total   1663200
```

and finally I want to have the following:

```
Time    Geography           Sex     Population
1990    Northern Ireland    Male    792100
1990    Northern Ireland    Female  831100
1990    Northern Ireland    Total   1623300
1991    Northern Ireland    Male    792100
1991    Northern Ireland    Female  831100
1991    Northern Ireland    Total   1623300
1992    Northern Ireland    Male    792100
1992    Northern Ireland    Female  831100
1992    Northern Ireland    Total   1623300
1993    Northern Ireland    Male    812100
1993    Northern Ireland    Female  851100
1993    Northern Ireland    Total   1663200
```

meaning that basically I want to fill in the values of the previous years with the values of the first year without NAs.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can chain [`pandas.DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), [`pandas.DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with method `bfill` and after that [`pandas.DataFrame.sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) to get your original index back in order:

```
df = df.sort_values(['Sex']).fillna(method='bfill').sort_index()

print(df)
   Time         Geography     Sex  Population
0  1990  Northern Ireland    Male    792100.0
1  1990  Northern Ireland  Female    831100.0
2  1990  Northern Ireland   Total   1623300.0
3  1991  Northern Ireland    Male    792100.0
4  1991  Northern Ireland  Female    831100.0
5  1991  Northern Ireland   Total   1623300.0
6  1992  Northern Ireland    Male    792100.0
7  1992  Northern Ireland  Female    831100.0
8  1992  Northern Ireland   Total   1623300.0
```

Comment: I like your method better.   Nice answer +1

Comment: Thank you sir, appreciate that @ScottBoston

Comment: Hey, thank you for this. I think that it works. Just to make sure however that I want to fill in the values of the previous years with the values of the first year without NAs. I do not want any `Population` values of the rows which do have values to change.

Comment: I understand. This works with the example you shown, but the key for this solution is that the sorting is correct. So without more example datasets we cannot test. If your dataset provided is representative for your real case dataset. This works. If you have more questions, please ask, happy to help @PoeteMaudit

Comment: No I think that it still works. I just edited my post by adding some values for 1993 to show that these values and any other values which do not contain NAs after the 1992 should not be affected.

Comment: So I think that everything is fine since since fillna(method='bfill') won't change apparently the already filled values.

Comment: Yes, its only to fill `NaN` @PoeteMaudit, and backfill stands for `backwardsfill`

Comment: Hey, I tested again more thoroughly. Are sure that it works? I think not.

Comment: Ah ok I think that I fixed that. The problem is that I have actually an additional column to the dataframe and I have to .sort_values by it too (unless I am missing something).

Comment: Yes that could be the case @PoeteMaudit, like I said, the `sorting` is key here.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
df.set_index(['Time','Geography','Sex']).unstack().bfill().stack().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   Time         Geography     Sex  Population
0  1990  Northern Ireland  Female    831100.0
1  1990  Northern Ireland    Male    792100.0
2  1990  Northern Ireland   Total   1623300.0
3  1991  Northern Ireland  Female    831100.0
4  1991  Northern Ireland    Male    792100.0
5  1991  Northern Ireland   Total   1623300.0
6  1992  Northern Ireland  Female    831100.0
7  1992  Northern Ireland    Male    792100.0
8  1992  Northern Ireland   Total   1623300.0
```

Comment: Thank you for this but I want the order of the rows to be maintained as I show at my output above.

Answer (score 1):

I will using `groupby` and `bfill` and `ffill`(I am adding `ffill` and `bfill` just for protection)

```
df['Population']=df.groupby(['Geography','Sex']).Population.apply(lambda x : x.ffill().bfill())
df
   Time        Geography     Sex  Population
0  1990  NorthernIreland    Male    792100.0
1  1990  NorthernIreland  Female    831100.0
2  1990  NorthernIreland   Total   1623300.0
3  1991  NorthernIreland    Male    792100.0
4  1991  NorthernIreland  Female    831100.0
5  1991  NorthernIreland   Total   1623300.0
6  1992  NorthernIreland    Male    792100.0
7  1992  NorthernIreland  Female    831100.0
8  1992  NorthernIreland   Total   1623300.0
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for this. I think that it works. Just to make sure however that I want to fill in the values of the previous years with the values of the first year without NAs. I do not want any `Population` values of the rows which do have values to change.

Comment: @PoeteMaudit if so `df['Population']=df.groupby(['Geography','Sex']).Population.bfill()` also , when you last year is NaN , if without groupby the output will not correct